# Transforming multidimensional array into array of objects. Nested loops vs callbacks

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, transformation

I am currently working on a very popular JS objects problem: transformEmployeeData. I had gotten my solution mapping the argument array and its inner arrays. I am happy with that. BUT, my first attempt to solve this same problem was to create two loops, nest them and create my object. This solution, for some reason, is not giving me the expected result and, I WANT TO KNOW WHY IS THIS HAPPENING? As I said, my interest is to learn well how JS works. Not only get my specs to run. Thanks.

Here the already working code:

```
    function transformEmployeeData(array) {   
  return array.map(function(outterArr){
        const finalObj = {};
        outterArr.map(function(innerArr){
           finalObj[innerArr[0]] = innerArr[1];
         });
         return finalObj;   }); }
```

Its returning value (which is the expected one) :

```
[ { firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk' },   {
 firstName: 'Mary',
     lastName: 'Jenkins',
     age: 36,
    role: 'manager' } ]
```

My first attempt (the one I can't understand why it doesn't return the above value):

```
    function transformEmployeeData(array) {  
     let finalArr = [];   
const finalObj = {};  
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i +=1){
        let outterArr = array[i];
      for (let j = 0; j < outterArr.length; j+=1){
          let innerArr = outterArr[j];
          finalObj[innerArr[0]] = innerArr[1];    
    }   
     finalArr.push(finalObj);   
    }  
     return finalArr; 
    }
```

its return value (the weird one... to me):

```
[ { firstName: 'Mary',
    lastName: 'Jenkins',
    age: 36,
    role: 'manager' },
  { firstName: 'Mary',
    lastName: 'Jenkins',
    age: 36,
    role: 'manager' } ]
```

Th original data:

```
var employeeData = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
    ]
];
```

Comment: why `map` without using the returned array? please add the original data as well.

Comment: Included @NinaScholz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `finalObj` once, but you update and push it multiple times. Since the same object is pushed into the array, all items show the values that were assigned in the last loop. On each iteration create a new `finalObj`:

```js
function transformEmployeeData(array) {
  const finalArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    const finalObj = {};
    const outterArr = array[i];
    
    for (let j = 0; j < outterArr.length; j += 1) {
      const innerArr = outterArr[j];
      finalObj[innerArr[0]] = innerArr[1];
    }
    
    finalArr.push(finalObj);
  }
  return finalArr;
}

const employeeData = [[["firstName","Joe"],["lastName","Blow"],["age",42],["role","clerk"]],[["firstName","Mary"],["lastName","Jenkins"],["age",36],["role","manager"]]];

console.log(transformEmployeeData(employeeData));
```

You can also use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of the standard for loop:

```js
function transformEmployeeData(array) {
  const finalArr = [];

  for (const outterArr of array) {
    const finalObj = {};
    
    for (const innerArr of outterArr) {
      finalObj[innerArr[0]] = innerArr[1];
    }
    
    finalArr.push(finalObj);
  }
  return finalArr;
}

const employeeData = [[["firstName","Joe"],["lastName","Blow"],["age",42],["role","clerk"]],[["firstName","Mary"],["lastName","Jenkins"],["age",36],["role","manager"]]];

console.log(transformEmployeeData(employeeData));
```

Comment: Got it!!! Thanks, @Ori Drori. I couldn't catch that out after looking at the code for so long !!